# Problems deleting table/database items with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Right now I've got a couple of AJAX methods for this task organizer project I'm working on--so far I've only got the insert working and delete partially working. For some reason I can't figure out why I'm unable to delete a new entry before refreshing the page. The code that the PHP generates (the fifth echo down from the while shows where I'm passing the ID that correlates with my database taskID):

```
function generateTaskTable(){
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', '-', '-');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("tasks", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tasks order by taskDate ASC");
    echo '<table id="task_table">';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $id = $row['taskID'];
        echo '<tr id="row'.$id.'">';
        echo '<td>'.convertDate($row['taskDate']).'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['hours'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$row['task'].'</td>';
        echo '<td><a href=""><img src="images/trash.png" class="delete" name="'.$id.'"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="images/delete.png" class="unsuccessful"></a>
        <a href=""><img src="images/check.png" class="successful"></a></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
    mysql_close($con);
}
```

JQuery/Ajax calls:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.delete').click(function(e){
            var deleteID = $(this).attr('name');
            var row = deleteID;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: "deleteID="+ deleteID,
                success: function(result){
                    $('#row'+row).fadeOut('fast');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        $("form#submit").submit(function(e) {

            var day = $('#dayDD').val();
            var month = $('#monthDD').val();
            var year = $('#yearDD').val();
            var hours = $('#hours_text').val();
            var task = $('#task_text').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: "day=" + day + "&month=" + month + "&year=" + year + "&hours=" + hours + "&task=" + task,
                success: function(result){
                    $('#hours_text').val('');
                    $('#task_text').val('');
                    $('#task_table').append(result);
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

ajax.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['deleteID'])){
    deleteTask($_POST['deleteID']); 
}

if (isset($_POST['task'])&& isset($_POST['hours'])){
    $newID = insertTask();
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $day = $_POST['day'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];
    $task = $_POST['task'];
    $hours = $_POST['hours'];
    $day = str_pad($day, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

    echo'<tr id="row'.$newID.'"><td>'.$month.' '.$day.', '.$year.'</td><td>'.$hours.'</td><td>'.$task.'</td><td><a href=""><img src="images/trash.png" class="delete" name="'.$newID.'"></a><a href=""><img src="images/delete.png" class="unsuccessful"></a><a href=""><img src="images/check.png" class="successful"></a></td></tr>';
}
```

The bottom of ajax.php shows the code that's going back to the AJAX call. When I view the generated source it once adding a new entry, the new generated ID is correct and properly assigned to the image name--but it's not working correctly. Instead of getting deleted from the table and from my database the page refreshes and the item doesn't get deleted until you click the image again. I've also noticed the icon alignment is slightly off, which I have no idea why because the generated source shows the exact same format as all the other table items.

Delete function:

```
function deleteTask($id){
    $con = mysql_connect('localhost', '-', '-');
    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("tasks", $con);
    $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM tasks WHERE taskID=$id");
    mysql_close($con);
}
```

Edit: Okay, I think I might know what's going wrong with this from looking around some other Stack Overflow posts--perhaps my JQuery `$('.delete').click` function is not working because it's running only when document.ready fires. The PHP generated JQuery that comes back and creates another table element on the page has the correct ID tag in order to be deleted but document.ready has already made the elements with the class "delete" clickable (just not the new one). Would this be a possibility? If so, how can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just add `e.stopPropagation();` in your `onClick` handler for element with class `.delete`

Comment: I was using e.preventDefault() before... would e.stopPropagation() be the better way to go for this?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Just needed to add `$(".delete").live('click',function(e){` to bind an event to a dynamic element.

Answer (score 0):

Your page refreshes because of link `<a href="">` around your trash button. Try putting

`javascript:void(0);`

as

`<td><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="images/trash.png" class="delete" name="'.$id.'"></a>`

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could upvote, I'm under 15 points right  now. But that solved the refresh problem--it's still not deleting for some reason.

Comment: Edited to include delete function

Comment: Double check that you are getting the right $id in deleteTask method by logging /echoing. Also, if you have foreign key references of this task id in other tables, you won't be able to delete it (unless you have DELETE CASCADE.

Comment: Is returned $result == true? You need to do lot of logging and identify the exact point of failure.

Answer (score -1):

Use GET instead of POST in your AJAX, just remove the post and data bits and set the URL to:

```
url: "ajax.php?deleteID=" + deleteID
```

Ofcourse, also update the delete php to use $_GET instead of $_POST.

Comment: Thanks but it's still refusing to delete the item. If I click delete for any of the other items they get removed just fine. Odd.

Comment: No no no no no. _Never_ use delete queries on a GET call. A spider can quite happily 'index' all your content, thus deleting everything. Even if it's hidden behind a firewall, or requires logging in, that sort of prevents it, this is very dangerous and easily avoidable. The 'GET' method is *only* for retrieving data.